# What does `[ERROR] Nothing <: com.some.SomeType?` mean?

Tags: java, scala, maven, scala-compiler

I have a project with scala and java. For scala compilation scala-maven-plugin is used.

So during the build there are some messages like that:

```
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:3.1.6:testCompile (scala-test-compile) @ project_name ---
...    
[ERROR] Nothing <: com.some.SomeType?
[INFO] true
...
```

What does it mean? The source of scala class is below:

```
package com.some

package object model {

  type SomeType = List[String]

  object SomeType {
    def apply(msg: String): SomeType = List(msg)
  }

  type SecondType[I] = AnyRef {
    def id: I
    def version: Long
  }

  type AnotherSecondType = SecondType[Another] {
    def id: Another
    def version: Long
  }

}
```

**P.S.** Also, there are other such message pairs for other scala classes.

**UPDATED**
Maven build completes **successfull**, but I have these messages in the log.

Comment: I do not think you've pasted the right thing. Type `Another` does not exist. By declaring it, compilation works. No question mark needed in that log line, since `Nothing` really is a subtype of everything, so that exposed relationship is correct. And when pasting errors - don't omit so much.

Comment: `Another` and `SecondType` just other scala classes in other packages.

Comment: Also I pay your attantion that this message appearace **does not** mean that build crushes. Instead build finishes complete, but I have these messages in the log.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have `-explaintypes` enabled in your Scala compiler options. Open your `pom.xml` and check the `<plugin><plugins>` entry for `scala-maven-scala`. See if in `<configuration><args>` you have `<arg>-explaintypes</arg>`. These messages can sometimes aid in cleaning up type errors in your code but I find them too annoying to keep them on all the time.